# Enable Custom Fields For Custom Post Type When CPT Created Using Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

My CPT is created using a plugin so i cannot edit the supports parameter to add support for custom fields.

I tried using this code however it doesn't work either

```
add_action('init', 'custom_child_init');
function custom_child_init() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-fields' );
}
```

How do i enable the custom field meta box on the Edit Page screen for single custom post types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this. just change `CPT` with your post type.

```
function wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_cpt() {
    add_post_type_support( 'CPT', 'custom-fields' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_cpt' );
```